# Python create both sync and async function in same main

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

I need to have two function in my Python 3.11 code.

One function must be sync, it retrive some data from a local machine so i need to wait to finish.
Another function must be async, it get the data from the first function and send to the server. Since i don't know how many time can be (5 seconds to 30 seconds) this function must doesn't interrupt the first one

Pratically, the second function start always when the first finish but the first always start and don't care about the second one. This code run H24

My attempt:

```
import time
import asyncio

async def task1():
    print("Recover data... waiting")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("End data recover")
    return "slow"

async def task2(p):
    print("I'm so" + p)
    time.sleep(10)
    print("END--->")

async def main():
    while True:
        print("create task1 and wait to finish")
        x = await task1()
        print("create task2 and not wait to finishing")
        asyncio.create_task(task2(x))

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.create_task(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

I dont' need to use asyncio like a requirement, i just want to meet the goal without run out all the memory of the machine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

basically, "yes". Like in: that is the way you do it. If you need some task to complete before goind on with code in a given place, the thing to do is to wait for that data - if it is in an async func, then you use the `await`  keyword, just as depicted in the code above.

If there  are *other* tasks in parallel to calling `main`, then it would be nice if the code in `task1` would return execution to the asyncio.loop while it waits for its result - That code could run in another thread, with the use of `await asyncio.run_in_executor(sync_call, args)` or simply await asyncio.sleep(...)`